# How to get file size

Tags: hadoop

I am running a hadoop job, I have FileSystem object and Path object and I want to know what is the file (Path) size.

any idea?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
long length = FileSystem#getFileStatus(PATH)#getLen();
```

[Here is a link to the relevant documentation of Hadoop 2.2.0](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)%20Here)

Comment: Not sure when it changed, but it's now `getFileStatus` instead of `getStatus`.

Answer (score 2):

another API is(written in Scala):

```
    private def getFileSizeByPath(arg : String): Long = {
      val path = new Path(arg)
      val hdfs = path.getFileSystem(new Configuration())
      val cSummary = hdfs.getContentSummary(path)
      val length = cSummary.getLength
      length
    }
```

Note that the return Long type is Byte in size.