# Getting the filesize in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to get the size of a file in Spark without pouring it into an RDD. How Can I do that? I don't  want to pour it into a RDD since it can cause an overload to my application and my files are large.

Comment: What do you mean "pour into RDD"? As soon as you read a file, it creates an RDD, which is an abstraction, not a data-structure with an actual size until it is collected

Comment: Can I just read this info from file properties so not have to read all contents to a RDD? maybe using a simple java API..i guessing reading to an RDD and then estimating the size make spark read all conexstes as long my file it is large its extra overhead..

Comment: Where is the file stored? HDFS or S3? You can read the file size directly from those respective Java API, yes

Comment: wanted to know if there is anything in Spark?

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Where is the file stored?

Comment: on one HDFS directory in the cluster

Comment: And why can't you just use Java HDFS API? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167153/how-to-get-file-size As I said, Spark isn't the solution and RDD's don't have a "size"